# paypal ipn and mysql

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm struggling with this problem for some days now but with no success, I'm relatively
new to paypal ipn but have used it succesfully in the past few monhts, now maybe I'm
doing some silly mistake or paypal sandbox ipn server is unresponsible.

**The payment is processed properly, the money goes from the buyer account to the seller but still no details are entered in the database.**

So this is the html form code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sanboxselleremail">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.com/testipn/">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mysite.com/testipn/">
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com/testipn/ipn.php" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is the ipn code that I found at paypal:

```
include('db.php');

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

if($payment_status=='Completed'){

 $paylog = $db->query("INSERT INTO....);

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

I've double checked everything, I know that you must post back all the variables so I checked them too. The sql syntax has no problems because I've tested it and it enters
the values to the database table I want.

Can you please take a quick look and please point any errors you might find?

Thank you.
This problem is costing me lot of time and stress... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is outdated and doesn't include the HTTP 'Host' header, which is (now) required.
So with this code, it would never get back 'VERIFIED', but instead get a HTTP/1.1 400 'Bad Request' back from PayPal.

To fix this, simply change:
`$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";`

To:
`$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";`

And add:
`$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";`

Should you just wish to use updated sample code, you can find this at https://www.paypal.com/ipn/

Comment: Thank you. I will test this code right now :) and will let you know.Thank you.

Comment: I've been trying to dayysss that sh*t really got me stressed. Thank you for your suggestion. I really appreciate it. God bless you, god bless stackoverflow too :)

Answer (score 0):

hi  it seems to me its blocked as dont regcongnise you when it trys to complete the process ,ive read alot of people are experiencing problems with the sandbox theres a thing on paypal that tells you about it brb ill find 
easily solved you need a buyer sandbox account and a seller one do you have both sorry for my spelling hope this helps
use this to test it 
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_testing_SBAccessing